# ASP.NET Master Page and Kendo UI Mobile Views

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, kendo-ui

Let's say I have to use an ASP master page and setup a Kendo UI Mobile layout in it, while using the `<asp:contentplaceholder>` to load aspx page content. To have this working properly, I have tried the following(stripping tag attributes here for readability):

**Master Page File:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form>
        <asp:contentplaceholder></asp:contentplaceholder>    
    </form>

    <!-- Master Layout -->
    <div data-role="layout" data-id="mMasterLayout">
        <header data-role="header">
        </header>
        <footer data-role="footer">
        </footer>
    </div>

    <!-- load scripts here (jquery, kendo, etc.) -->

    <script>
        var app;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.forms, {
                layout: "mMasterLayout"
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Some other page using the Master Page File:**

```
<asp:Content>
    <!-- View -->
    <div data-role="view">    
        <!-- Content -->
        <div data-role="content">
            .
            .
            .
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

So, inspecting the DOM I find no errors and Kendo is rendering appropriately. The problem is, my screen is blank (only see the body background color). In the DOM, the expected view to be shown is infact visible.

Anyone have any thoughts to help? I feel like targeting the form container for Kendo to render my views is the culprit, but I'm not sure. I also tried inheriting the width and height of the body tag to see if that might help but it did nothing.

Also, please note that I have to make it work this way, as the solution is not setup as MVC so no MVVM or anything like that is a possibility.

I am using the latest release of both Kendo UI Mobile and JQuery.
Thank you!

**Update:**

Hardcoding a fixed height for the `form` tag in my master page file does yield the desired contents of my view. The question left I suppose is.. what is the best way to expand this form tag to the height of the document body..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own solution - Add the following CSS property to the master page file:

`html { height: 100%; }`